# If the set increases in size add the word to the dict as a key with the value being the new length of the set

Tags: python, set

If the set increases in size (indicating this word has not been processed before), 
add the word to the dict as a key with the value being the new length of the set.
Using another loop, display the list of words in the dict along with their value, 
which represents the order in which they were discovered by the program.

```
freq= {} # empty dict
wordSet = set() # empty set
while True:
    text=input ("Write sentence:")
    if not text:
        print ("Finished")
        break

    else:
        for punc in (".,?;!"):
            text = text.replace (punc, "")#replace punctuation with empty string
        for word in text.lower().split():#split text into words
            wordSet.add(word)#loop and add words to the set
            count =len(wordSet)
            freq[word] = count
            print (freq)
```

The result should look like this:

```
Enter text: how now brown cow
how 1
now 2
cow 4
brown 3
Enter text: the cow jumped over the moon
brown 3
cow 4
jumped 6
over 7
moon 8
how 1
the 5
now 2
```

Comment: We are not here to do your homework and you didn't ask a real question. Please describe your problem specifically and we might help you.

Comment: are you getting some kind of error? that would be helpful ;)

Comment: I would like to get just the word and the (word count), but now I am getting:{'how': 1}
{'how': 1, 'now': 2}
{'how': 1, 'now': 2, 'brown': 3}
{'how': 1, 'now': 2, 'cow': 4, 'brown': 3} instead o how 1 now 2 brown 3 cow 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing my answer on your comment...

Instead of

```
for word in text.lower().split():#split text into words
    [...]
    print (freq)
```

It should be

```
for word in text.lower().split():#split text into words
    [...]
print (freq)
```

So that you're printing once all the words have been encountered.

Whenever you have a problem like this, it's always good to make sure your `print`s are where they should be.

Comment: @rdrey, @Holger Just-Thanks a lot:) Thanks for your suggestions.